# emacs in putty session on fedora under virtual box on windows 10 hangs on X11 paste

Tags: copy-paste, fedora

I suffer a rangy environment where I typically will run emacs in a putty session on fedora under virtual box on windows 10. Sometimes (not all of the time), pasting into the emacs will hang the session. I've found this discussed in a lot of places, but no remedy seems to fix the problem. Does anybody out there have a good remedy?

Comment: Can you make your post clearer by mentioning which operating system is the host and which one is the guest? Also, how exactly do you paste into Emacs?

Comment: Thanks @DoMiNeLa 10.    ---- fedora 28 guest under windows 10 host. Putty running on windows 10 host or on windows 10 laptop on the network. Pasting into emacs running as a tty application (emacs -nw) in the Putty window with mouse operation, cutting from either Linux window (perhaps another Putty window) or from a Windows window. No rhyme or reason to the hang, although once I've found one it hangs on a second try, but not always when I go back to reproduce the problem.

Comment: And it's always frustrating when I post a question on a problem and don't get an answer and when it happens again I search for an answer and find my original question ;-)